# How to generate unique 4 to 7 characters key

Tags: algorithm, cryptography

I need to generate a huge amount of codes for a raffle, the code shouldnt be too long since we dont want the user to have a hard time entering the code in a website, how could I know how many codes would it take for my algorithm to repeat a code again? and how could I generate the codes? the code can be both numbers and letters.

Comment: How about `00001` , `00002`, ... ?

Comment: Random 7 character keys using characters from 0-9, a-z and A-Z will on average produce collisions after 2 million strings, but it can happen earlier. I recommend a stateful generator, such as a counter.

Comment: The general formula is n^l with n being the number of characters per position and l the length of the string. On average, you’ll get a collision after n^l/2 codes.

Comment: @HenkHolterman thats guessable.

Comment: What exactly is "a huge amount"? If You need less than one million codes, numeration of all numbers between `000000` to `999999` sufffices.

Comment: @Lenin - yes, but what's wrong with that? The numbers in most lotteries are guessable.

Comment: Something to consider is to exclude numbers that look like letters, and then alternate numbers and letters. If you don't do that, you can get values that may "offend" people ("screwu", or much worse). We ran into this when generating user ids. A bad word lookup will always miss some, so better to make the generation algorithm not allow formation of anything that could be deemed a word.

Comment: Looks like you are looking at the wrong side of the problem. If you want to generate serial keys, then your software needs to accept say 1 mln different serial keys. You can have a function which will validate them all. The hacker, however, will need to find any of those 1 mln numbers. With 7-char number this will require the hacker to test 1 727 094 keys (based on calculations of Guffa in another answer). Such number of serial keys is not hard to enumerate in a reasonable amount of time, and finding any of those numbers will give the hacker a valid number which they can distribute then.

Comment: @HenkHolterman instead of choosing 0-9 if you choose a larger set of alphanumeric characters its not only is easily unpredictable but also gives you a larger combinations.

Answer (score 3):

Uppsercase and lowerase letters and digits, removing easily confusable ones like for example `0`, `O`, `o`, `I`, `1`, `l`, gives you 56 different characters. For a code of the length x, you get 56 to the power of x possible combinations.

Four characters gives 9834496 different combinations.
Seven characters gives 1727094849536 different combinations.

To pick random combinations that are guaranteed to be unique, you simply have to keep all previous combinations that you created, and check each new one against them.

Comment: Doesn't work for "huge amount of codes", but I suspect the OP is exaggerating.

Comment: Might need to elaborate on the `check each new one against them` part: using linear search for it instead of hashset would be extremely inefficient.

Comment: Since you're apparently using case insensitive strings, you shouldn't subtract both `o` and `O` from the set.

Comment: @sampson-chen: A huge number of codes would most likely go into a database, so you would rather solve it using an index than a hashset. :)

Comment: I'd say a huge amount wouldn't fit a db, and a 7 char string is too short for that anyways. [(but perhaps doing crypto has warped my perception of "huge amount")](https://twitter.com/FakeIACR/statuses/249175009757630464)

Comment: @CodesInChaos yeah, I know what you mean, it is a very subjective term anyway

Answer (score 0):

Instead of starting at 0, you could start at the max. You'd first need to decide what characters will make up your list, and use that to create a look-up table of size m.

Create a random prime, p. Then you use a generator that starts at the max value, n = c ** m - 1, where c is the number of characters per code, then the key is, k = n % p. Then just convert that into a number in base m, which will allow for using the look-up table to create the string of characters.

Then just generate all the codes you need, either via generator function as they are needed or all at once. Although, you'll want to decrease n by randomBetween(n / (number of codes remaining)/2,n / (number of codes remaining)) or something similar, instead of just decreasing it by one, which could allow for p and/or n to be determined simply by brute force. Which also means that you perhaps shouldn't use the max value as key.

As long as p is much larger than the number of codes required, it won't repeat as long as p remains constant. It also may be cryptographically secure as long as no one knows what p is. Although p likely needs to be kept small as to avoid any chance of repetition p should be an actual prime, not a probable one, thus requiring upwards of exponential time to ensure that p is prime. Once you have the key generated though, it should be polynomial at worst to generate each keys. Although it's probably better to just generate all of the keys you need at once (make extras if you need to), store them, then distribute as needed. This way you can be sure the keys are unique, in the case something causes the key generator to fail, thus forcing to create a second value of p, or store the original value of p, making the value of p more likely to become known, although storing p (along with n) is required if you aren't storing the actual valid keys.

Limiting the number of times a key can be used or attributing it to an account, would help with avoiding the issue of hackers only needing to find one key then distribute it.